# Why set body font-size to 100%

Tags: responsive-design

According to this article on responsive web design you should set the body font-size to 100%. Ive also heard of this practice before.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/typography-articles/taking-the-erm-out-of-ems/

Why would you do this? Also what does it actually change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the font-size to 100% makes use of the user's default font configuration (People with visual impairment tend to increase it for example), by setting the percentage you are truly making a site that is adapting to the user's device .

Em on the other hand (quoting the article you referenced):

> An em is a unit of measurement. Just like pixels, ems can determine the size of elements on a web page. Unlike pixels, which are absolute, ems are relative to their parent’s font size, which is where a lot of confusion lies.

```
   desired pixel / inherited pixel  = em
```

So people use this to make the inherited pixel set to user default configuration.
Making it a bit unpredictable to control the font-size, one perfect example would be the multiple anchor tags in a paragraph that is referenced in the article as well:

> The anchor within the paragraph is still sized at 1.2em, but that’s now relative to the parent paragraph, which is already 19.2px – (1.2 * 19.2px = 23.04px). This gives us extra large anchors in some parts of our page; hardly desirable.

In short, using percentages makes the font-size global, using ems makes it relative to the inherited size.

Comment: I understand the 2nd part of your answer, but I still dont understand the first bit. When you say "font-size to 100% makes use of the user's default font configuration", what else would it be if you left this style out?

Comment: @jdln Depends on the browser's default font-size, each browser has it's own set of styling. font-size:100%; sets it to the user's computer font-size (the one you set via control panel)

Comment: Still seems to me that the most responsive approach would be to leave off the body text-size 100% as then your leaving it up to browser, device or user defaults.